# How do I keep my Windows install clean?

Tags: windows

I finally caved and nuked the Windows install I’ve been using since 2009 (originally XP, upgraded to 7, then 8.1, then 10). It was running fine but it had accumulated a lot of crap over the years and it’s undoing was an Xbox game, from Microsoft itself no less—Xbox on Windows is toxic stinking garbage.

I had dozens of customizations and re-doing them has been a giant pain. These include not just all my apps but also custom fonts, custom certificates, custom Outlook macros, custom task scheduler tasks, Hyper-V virtual machines, etc.

1. Is there a simple configuration manager for personal Windows installs that I can put all my customizations info and run post-Windows install?
2. Is there a way to keep my Windows install clean? Something like Docker that isolates an app’s files and registry to a container/virtual store and keeps it from crapping all over my C: drive and the real registry?

Comment: The design of the Windows registry makes this nigh-on impossible. It's monolithic. Whatever gets written to it needs the same pair of tweezers to remove. The closest you might get is to run something like Revo, to keep tabs on what went in, when you need to get it back out again.

Comment: Sadly, I think you're likely going to have to investigate running a custom script (or scripts) if you really want some reproducible set of customizations. That said, I believe PowerShell, maybe some [Python](https://www.python.org/) and perhaps a few independent third-party command line tools could essentially cover whatever customizations you wanted to reproduce.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a clean image that you can restore when required.

Comment: What I do, after clean install and full customization, I make a disk image of the drive, that way if for any reason I have to nuke it, i can restore the image that has most of the hard work already done.